# How to extract data from a URL fragment Django

Tags: django, spotify, supabase

Hi I'm trying to learn development by creating a web app that displays users top Spotify stats and so I'm trying to use supabase to login to Spotify however the redirect gives a URL in the form of:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/#access_token=

I'm currently working using Django and because the data is in a URL fragment I cant access it using request.get. How would I go about extracting the data from the URL.